# iphone addSubView to delegate from another view controller

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar

I'm trying to add a UIToolBar to my UITabBarController. Currently if I add it to the self.view in my UITableViewController and if you scroll down it will move the UIToolbar with it and disappear. So I need to add the UIToolBar to the UITabBarController from my UITableViewController, which is from a different controller. The UITabBarController is declared in the delegate.

Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the class with the table inherit from UIViewController, implement UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, and put the tableview on self.view underneath a toolbar you've put on self.view.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean? Are you saying I need to change the class to UIViewController from UITableViewController and add <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> to the current class. So it will look like this:

@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

and then simple add the UIToolBar and my new tableview variable to self.view?